# Play back an RTSP in Flash

Tags: flash, stream, video-encoding, rtsp, vlc

I have an IP camera streaming video through RTSP, and I am able to pick up the stream in VLC (rtsp://192.168.1.50:554/live.sdp). What I need now is a way to show this stream in a Flash application I am developing (probably through the FLVPlayback component?). This means I need a way to "convert" or transcode the RSTP stream to a format supported by Flash, live.

I searched around but couldn't find any conclusive answers... Should I use VLC to transcode the video stream? Something with Adobe Media Server? Is ffmpeg an option here? I have no clue where to start or which option is most suited in this case. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use erlyvideo streaming server to convert RTSP to RTMP. Flash can handle that natively. (http://erlyvideo.org/)

Comment: Is there a Windows solution for this problem? Otherwise, this is not a bad idea...

Comment: http://www.wowza.com/ looks like it might work on Windows, but I have no experience with it directly. It claims to be able to do what you want and it has a free download to test.

Comment: Yes, looks okay... Maybe I should have mentioned I'm a poor student and I don't have money to spend on such software, hehe.

But thank you for your help!

Comment: Here's an overview of your options: ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems ). If you find the answers helpful, please remember to accept it.

Comment: I have decided to go with erlyvideo after all. This seems like the most viable solution. However, I am still struggling with the configuration. As you know I have an rtsp stream that should be turned into an rtmp stream. In what way should I modify the erlyvideo.conf file to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Using VLC, you can transcode the stream on the fly using the command:

```
cvlc -vvv rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/vga.sdp :sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=0,acodec=none,deinterlace}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=127.0.0.1:8090/toFlashPlayer.flv}'
```

I use this to push an RTSP stream to Flowplayer embedded in a page on my local Apache server, and it works very well. There are other options available for controlling network caching, video and audio bitrate, as well as frame rate - Examples available [HERE](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aStreaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples).

Hope this helps!

Mason

Answer (score 0):

I use Wowza and Unreal Media Server for this purpose. These servers not only can output your RTSP camera content to RTMP (Flash), but also to MPEG-TS and other formats for other players.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Unreal Media Server support UMS, MS-WMSP- RTMP and more, this mean you can use this one for your project. You can take a look with this one http://www.umediaserver.net/umediaserver/index.html

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is a player which supports RTSP built for flash called [Locomote Video Player](https://github.com/AxisCommunications/locomote-video-player). Disclaimer: I am the author

It supports RTSP over TCP, RTSP over HTTP, RTMP in all its forms as well as mp4 and flv streaming.

It's open source and contributions are welcome.

Comment: It works if you can have flash enabled (which it should be possible to do in non-metro mode right). Forgive me, I'm not overly skilled on the Microsoft platform.